# CSS background color in div only 20px high

Tags: html, css

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    -ms-user-select: None; 
    -moz-user-select: None; 
    -webkit-user-select: None; 
}

html, body {
    font: 16px Helvetica;
    min-height: 100%;
}

#channel {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%); 
}

#channelName {
    border: 0px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    outline: none;
    font: 18px Helvetica;
}

#erstelleChannel {
    font: 18px Helvetica;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 0px 5px;
}

#erstelleChannel:hover {
    font: 18px Helvetica;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: darkgray;
    padding: 0px 5px;
}

#eingabe {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    border-top: 1px solid gray;
}

#eingabeUser {
    width: 18%;
    height: 25px;
    border: 0;
    outline: none;
}

#eingabeInhalt {
    width: 78%;
    height: 25px;
    border: 0;
    outline: none;
}

#sendeNachricht {
    display: none;
}

#header {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 25px;
}

#ausgabe {
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: beige;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

<div id="header"><div id="channelheader"></div><div id="typing"></div></div>
<div id="ausgabe"></div>
<div id="eingabe">
    <form>
        <input type="text" id="eingabeUser" placeholder="Name" required>
        <input type="text" id="eingabeInhalt" placeholder="Nachricht" required>
        <input type="submit" id="sendeNachricht">
    </form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

As you can see the background color in the `div` is just `20px` high because of the padding inside `#ausgabe`. I want the div to be colored completely from the upper line to the line at the bottom. How can I achieve that? I played with the height in the parent element `html` and `body`, it did not work. What else can I try? Browsing the web didn't help.

Comment: you have to set `height` to this div try `#ausgabe{height:100vh}`:

Comment: If I set `height` to 100% it still doesn't work

Comment: Try `vh` not `%`

Comment: Okay, now I got it full screen but it's higher than it should be. Also `#eingabe` got the same color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `height:100%` instead `min-height: 100%;` to `body`

and also set [`height: calc(100% - 115px);`](https://www.w3schools.com/csSref/func_calc.asp) to `#ausgabe`

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    -ms-user-select: None; 
    -moz-user-select: None; 
    -webkit-user-select: None; 
}

html, body {
    font: 16px Helvetica;
    height: 100%;
}

#channel {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%); 
}

#channelName {
    border: 0px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    outline: none;
    font: 18px Helvetica;
}

#erstelleChannel {
    font: 18px Helvetica;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 0px 5px;
}

#erstelleChannel:hover {
    font: 18px Helvetica;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: darkgray;
    padding: 0px 5px;
}

#eingabe {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    border-top: 1px solid gray;
}

#eingabeUser {
    width: 18%;
    height: 25px;
    border: 0;
    outline: none;
}

#eingabeInhalt {
    width: 78%;
    height: 25px;
    border: 0;
    outline: none;
}

#sendeNachricht {
    display: none;
}

#header {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 25px;
}

#ausgabe {
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: beige;
height:calc(100% - 115px);
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

<div id="header"><div id="channelheader"></div><div id="typing"></div></div>
<div id="ausgabe"></div>
<div id="eingabe">
    <form>
        <input type="text" id="eingabeUser" placeholder="Name" required>
        <input type="text" id="eingabeInhalt" placeholder="Nachricht" required>
        <input type="submit" id="sendeNachricht">
    </form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: As you can see the page is higher than before and also `#eingabe` is colored. I just want `#ausgabe` to be colored.

Comment: You can still see the color in `#eingabe`

Comment: `height: calc(100% - 116px);`

Comment: The fix in the last edit is correct, body,html should have a height of 100% and #ausgabe should have a height (or min-height) of 100% too. -100px (height of the fixed element) can be used to account for #eingabe that has position: fixed and is therefore taken out of the document flow.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

Add height to the div id #ausgabe and adjust it as per your desire. Example below:

```
#ausgabe {
    padding: 20px;
    height: 86vh; // <- adjust numeric value of this section until you 
    achieve your height
    background-color: beige;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the css file with id ausgabe, you may write

```
#ausgabe {
        height: 100%;
        background-color: beige;
    }
```

This will enforce the `<div>` to take the 100% of its space. You may now play with the height percentage until you are satisfied with the outcome. Alternately, you may add `padding: 100%;` instead of `height` and play with it. You may also try using only `padding-bottom: 100%;` and play around with it.

As shown below - please, change the `min-height` in `html,body {` selectors to `height`

```
html, body {
        font: 16px Helvetica;
        height: 100%;
    }
```

Hope this helped solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

replace `min-height: 100%;` with `height: 100%;` and add `height:calc(100% - 115px);` in #ausgabe

It will resolved your issue.